# Angular constants and values vs Requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to access a value from a controller and I'm using requirejs.

In app.js I got:

```
  //the module's name is 'app'
  module.constant('myVal', "some value");
```

The controller:

```
define(
    function defineController() {
        "use strict";
        var module = angular.module('someCtrl', ['app']);
        var controller = function someCtrl($scope, myVal) {
            console.log(myVal); //this returns undefined
        };

        module.controller('someCtrl', controller);
        controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
        return controller;
    }
);
```

The problem is that "myVal" is undefined. What might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure, you should do:

```
controller.$inject = ['$scope','myVal'];
```

Otherwise the DI framework of Angular will inject only the scope: it sees the `$inject`, so it does not "sense" the `myVal` function argument.